# Match some of regex conditions (3 out of 5)

Tags: regex

Let's say I have 5 conditions that I check with lookahead. I will call them

```
a, b, c, d, e
```

This would be my regex:

```
^(?=.*[a])(?=.*[b])(?=.*[c])(?=.*[d])(?=.*[e]).*$
```

[regex101 - test](https://regex101.com/r/G2qdBq/1)

this will match all permutation of a, b, c, d, e, but I want to match at least 3 out of 5 (not exclusive as 'hvd' pointed out)

Meaning this will pass:

```
abc
abcde
abbbbbe
abccee
cddbbbbbeee
```

But this won't

```
aaaaa
bbbaaaaa
```

EDIT:
The real usage is for password policy - 5 conditions (lower case, uppercase, special char, number, etc.) you must comply with x out of y conditions.

It's easily done in code, but this is theoretical question to push the limits of regex.

Comment: I think you have two options: 1) match every permutation of the 3 out of 5 or 2) capture the matches and check in code if 3 of the capture groups have data.

Comment: "this will match all permutation of a, b, c, d, e" -- Not exclusively though. It will happily report a match on `abcdef`.

Comment: You could combine them via the `OR` operator - or use subroutines if it is supported by your flavor.

Comment: This isn't a problem to solve with regexes alone. I suggest that in whichever language you're using, match the string separately against each of the five patterns and count how many return true.

Comment: I'm also interested how `abcde` should be considered in your case?

Comment: In addition: what are your real requirements? Maybe we can be of any help here.

Comment: use [`^(?=[abcde]+)(.).*(?!\1)(.).*(?!\2|\1).$`](https://regex101.com/r/NtgYdI/2)

Comment: I'm guessing `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. are not simple characters but some patterns. Can something be `a` and `b` at the same time? Would that satisfy both conditions or does it count only for one of them?

Comment: @ndn you are correct that they are patterns. I've edited the question. They should be mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`/^(?:(?=.*[a])(?:(?=.*[b])(?=.*(?:[c]|[d]|[e]))|(?=.*[c])(?=.*(?:[d]|[e])))|(?=.*[d])(?=.*[e])|(?=.*[b])(?:(?=.*[c])(?=.*[d])|(?=.*([c]|[d]))(?=.*[e]))|(?=.*[c])(?=.*[d])(?=.*[e])).*$/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/G2qdBq/4)

This basically has every permutation of the 5 possible patterns (but optimised a bit for code length).

Hard to be 100% sure it's working correctly, but I think I've got it pretty much there. ^^

Comment: I cannot argue with the results. For the effort alone it deserves accepted answer. EDIT: It matches 'de' as well even though it meets only two conditions, but close enough. I'm sure 100% regex isn't a way to go.